# will i lose my pictures during a factory reset?

Tags: google-play-store, factory-reset

I accidentally deleted my app store and cant figure out how to get it back or open it again. I've read that I should do a factory reset. What will I lose if I do that? Im worried about my pictures.

Answer (score 2):

A generic answer can be found in the [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset) [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info). Basically, it "empties" the `/cache` and `/data` partitions of your device, so all the apps you've installed and all your apps' data will be gone for good. This does not necessarily apply to data on your SDcard: while some devices/ROMs offer to "wipe" those along, this is not done in most cases (in my experience) – and when it's done then usually only when the user explicitly specified to do so.

Now for your specific problem: If you really *deleted* your app store, a *factory-reset* won't bring it back: gone is gone. If you're unsure on what made it disappear, and your device is not rooted, it's unlikely you've really deleted it; you might rather just have *disabled* it. So while a *factory-reset* in that case would bring it back, so would an atomics bomb kill a fly. Before you go to *factory-reset* your device, try the following:

1. Go to *Settings→Apps*
2. To be on the safe side, select the "All Apps" tab
3. Scroll to the very end of the list. On some devices/ROMs disabled apps end up there, and on all devices/ROMs I've seen disabled apps are marked "disabled". See if your app store is there.

   - If it's there: tap the entry to open it, push the "enable" button
   - If it's not there, scroll through the entire list: it might be ordered alphabetically or by some other criteria, and have the "disabled apps" mixed in. When found: see previous item (open, enable, done)

If you didn't succeed with those steps, you still can try a [factory-reset](/questions/tagged/factory-reset).